# Best way to set up a haskell development platform

Tags: programming, haskell

I've been developing in Haskell for a while. My question is: what's the easiest way to set up a reasonable development system for Haskell? I installed the official packages, but IMO it's not working very well and sometimes conflicting with Cabal installed packages.

Is there a better platform? I possibly want to install GHC 7.0 instead of the Haskell platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what's the easiest way to set up a reasonable development system for Haskell?

The easiest, and the most reasonable way to get a Haskell environment running is:

- `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform`

  or
- Click the package to install **[haskell-platform](http://packages.ubuntu.com/haskell-platform) [image: Install haskell-platform]**

[image]

The problem with the 7.0.1 *platform* is that it hasn't all been packaged up nicely for Ubuntu yet, it's still only recommended for early adopters and packagers.

Comment: My problem is, that ubuntu dosn't presents all of the packages available on hackage. But if I install these with Cabal, the depencies may get mixed up. Also, Ubuntu never updates the packages, which is needed some times.

Comment: That's right, this package provides a 'standard library', meaning it has dependable versions and is rarely updated for maximum compatibility. If you want all of the latest, you will have to do a complete manual set up of your environment - which isn't easy and straightforward (If you do want to do that, go ahead and ask another question - make it specific to 7.0.1). - But just to be clear, this easy method is tailored towards compatibility and portability.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at the 'suggested packages' that apt displays when you install this meta package from the command line.

Comment: If you read my question twice, you might have seen, that I pointed towards something like this. But if it's really needed, I'm going to open a new question.